# How to disable air plane mode on locked Samsung Galaxy A51?

Tags: samsung, locked-out, airplane-mode

I'm locked out of my Samsung Galaxy A51 - forgot the PIN password and can't get back in. The phone is stuck on flight mode.

I'm trying to enter the phone without losing any data at all. Is there a way to enable it without doing a hard reset?

Comment: The quick settings should be accessible even if the phone is locked (slide down from the top of the screen). Usually there is the Wifi and the Airplane button in quick settings which allow to enable/disable wifi and mobile network.

Comment: @Robert, the question title is incorrect as the OP is actually trying to get in, as they have forgotten the pin.  Airplane mode is a red herring.

Comment: Thank you to bot of you.

Comment: But yes Rohit is right, i forget the pin so i cant take off the airplane mode even by the quick slide down menu. What is red herring? Do you know of any way to love my problem? Thanks again!